# How do you call a function that takes no inputs within a pipeline?

Tags: r, pipe, tidyverse, pipeline, magrittr

I tried searching for this but couldn't find any similar questions. Let's say, for the sake of a simple example, I want to do the following using `dplyr`'s pipe `%>%`.

`c(1,3,5) %>% ls() %>% mean()`

*Setting aside what the use case would be for a pipeline like this*, how can I call a function "mid-pipeline" that doesn't need any inputs coming from the left-hand side and just pass them along to the next function in the pipeline? Basically, I want to put an "intermission" or "interruption" of sorts into my pipeline, let that function do its thing, and then continue on my merry way. *Obviously*, the above doesn't actually work, and I know the T pipe `%T>%` also won't be of use here because it still expects the middle function to need inputs coming from the lhs. Are there options here shy of assigning intermediate objects and restarting the pipeline?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the ‘magrittr’ pipe operator you can put an operand inside `{…}` to prevent automatic argument substitution:

```
c(1,3,5) %>% {ls()} %>% mean()
# NA
# Warning message:
# In mean.default(.) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

… but of course this serves no useful purpose.

Incidentally, `ls()` inside a pipeline is executed in its own environment rather than the calling environment so its use here is even *less* useful. But a different function that returned a sensible value *could* be used, e.g.:

```
c(1,3,5) %>% {rnorm(10)} %>% mean()
# [1] -0.01068046
```

Or, if you intended for the left-hand side to be passed on, skipping the intermediate `ls()`, you could do the following:

```
c(1,3,5) %>% {ls(); .} %>% mean()
# [1] 3
```

… again, using `ls()` here won’t be meaningful but some other function that has a side-effect would work.

Comment: The function I had in mind was `gc()`, tbh, even though I know that it may not be of much effect. I am working with really large matrices in my pipeline so clearing up some garbage in between steps seems like something worth trying at least.

Comment: @Bajcz I see. Yes, if the `gc()` function actually did anything then this *might* be a valid use-case — but as you seem to know, `gc()` doesn’t actually do anything useful: if R runs out of memory during allocations it will run the GC automatically anyway.

Comment: Well, and plus my own curiosity! :) Pipes are useful...it's nice to know how you could break the rules sometimes...

Answer (score 2):

You could define an auxilliary function like this, that takes an argument it doesn't use in order to allow it to fit in the pipe:

```
ls_return_x <- function(x){
  print(ls()) 
  x
}
c(1,3,5) %>% ls() %>% mean()
```

Note, the `ls()` call in this example will print the objects in the environment within the `ls_return_x()` function. Check out the help page for `ls()` if you want to print the environment from the global environment.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there is an inbuilt function but you could certainly create a helper function for this

```
> callfun <- function(x, fun){fun(); return(x)}
> c(1, 3, 5) %>% callfun(fun = ls) %>% mean()
# [1] 3
```

I don't really see the point but hey - it's your life.

Comment: See my comment to @Konrad Rudolph above.